# Is there a name for this type of set function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, soft-question, category-theory

Let $Y$ be a set and $\mathcal{P}(Z)$ is a powerset of some set $Z$ (so the elements of $\mathcal{P}(Z)$ are sets themselves).

Let $f:\mathcal{P}(Z)\to Y$ be a set function.

Let $W\subseteq Y$ (fixed $W$).

Suppose we have this condition:

If $S\in f^{-1}(W)$, then for all $T\supseteq S$, we have $f(T)\in W$.

($f^{-1}$  denotes preimage)

Is there a special name for such a function? It's ok if the answer is no, I am just curious if there is some name e.g. "inclusion preserving, inclusion reversing" to describe it. Nomenclature from category theory will be very welcome.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems very odd and out of context. Where did you come across something like this, mixing $\in$ and $\subseteq$ so badly?

Comment: There's something weird : you write "$S\in f^{-1}(W)$", so $S$ is an element of $X$. What does it mean then that $S\subset T$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. $X$ is meant to be a powerset (of some set), so the elements of $X$ are sets themselves.

Comment: That makes more sense. I think it would be easier to understand if you simply replaced $X$ by $P(Z)$, for example. Also : do you want the property to hold for all $W$ or just for one?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Just one $W$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks. Even though $S$ is a set, $f(S)$ is supposed to be a single element (in $Y$).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli $W$ is not a point of $Y$, it is a subset. Hence $f^{-1}(W) = \{ U \in \mathcal P(Z) : f(U) \in W \}$ (in fact "$f(U) = W$" is ill typed so you shouldn't be able to write it).

Comment: @pece Oh, true. I was indeed confusing stuff.